# Can't access to my api Express.js from Angular6, running on the server

Tags: typescript, express, ssh, angular6

I upload my Angular app on Godaddy Host in public_html dir, with api Express.js in public_html/web-api.
About node in the host, it works correcly because I run it with ssh 
and I have a console log with init db:
[img console ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3UVo.png)
but when I get request to API, ii seems like angular don't redirect. And the console ssh don't show nothing.
What I need to put in my enviroment and proxy.conf in production?
Locally I did not have any problems.
Need I write the port or the folder where my APi is?

```js
//enviroment.prod
export const environment = {
  production: true, 
  apiUrl: ['https://web.com'],
};
```

```js
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://web.com/web-api",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

files on host:
public_html

> dir:web-api

Thank you for the support!!!

Comment: Could you please add more info on what you are trying to achieve? What's the result you are getting, and what did you expect to happen.

Comment: I am trying to post on Firebase newsletter data and send mail with Nodemailer. But it doesn’t matter this functions now, I just want to connect the api in the server with proxy and I don’t now how I need to write correctly the urls in the codes added, like with port or the dir where is the api on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Locally I specified the port of api:

```js
//Proxy.conf.json
 {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```